# Сортировка по очкам PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

1. Как сделать чтобы данные `Name` и `Points` были связаны друг с другом, т.к. это очки у определенного игрока.
2. Как сделать сортировку по очкам?

Прошу помощи либо кодом, либо советами про поиск информации полезной для решения данного вопроса.

---

**widgets.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class CustomTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):

    def KeyPressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QKeyEvent):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            print(" ")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            print(" ")
```

**counter.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from widgets import CustomTableWidget


class Counter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Counter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Formula1", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        self.setFont(font)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)

        table = CustomTableWidget(self)
        table.setColumnCount(2)
        table.setRowCount(1)

        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name" , "Points"])

        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setToolTip("Player 1")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setToolTip("Player 2")

        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        table.setItem(0, 0, self.createItem("25", QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled))
        table.setItem(0, 1, self.createItem("18", QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled))

        table.resizeColumnsToContents()
 
        sort_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Sort")
        apply_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Apply")

        horisontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(sort_button)
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(apply_button)
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        grid_layout.addLayout(horisontal_layout, 0, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 1, 0)
 
    def createItem(self, text, flags):
        tableWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text)
        tableWidgetItem.setFlags(flags)
        return tableWidgetItem


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = Counter()
    window.setWindowTitle("Counter")
    window.setMinimumSize(480, 120)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать:

- класс `QTableView` предоставляет реализацию модели/представления 
  по умолчанию для табличного представления. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html
- класс `QStandardItemModel` предоставляет общую модель для хранения пользовательских данных. 
  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html
- класс `QSortFilterProxyModel` обеспечивает поддержку сортировки и фильтрации данных 
  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan ,
  в котором переопределить метод `lessThan` 
  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan

то ваша задача может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from widgets import CustomTableWidget
#class CustomTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
class CustomTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):                               # QTableView !!!
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def KeyPressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QKeyEvent):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            print("Key_Enter ")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            print("Key_Return ")


# пользовательская реализация для сортировки по числам
class NumberSortModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def lessThan(self, left_index: "QModelIndex",
                 right_index: "QModelIndex") -> bool:

        left_var: str = left_index.data(Qt.EditRole)
        right_var: str = right_index.data(Qt.EditRole)

        try:
            return float(left_var) < float(right_var)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass

        try:
            return left_var < right_var
        except TypeError:  # in case of NoneType
            return True


class Counter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Counter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Formula1", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        self.setFont(font)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)

        '''
        table = CustomTableWidget(self)
        table.setColumnCount(2)
        table.setRowCount(1)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name" , "Points"])
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setToolTip("Player 1")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setToolTip("Player 2")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        table.setItem(0, 0, self.createItem("25", QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled))
        table.setItem(0, 1, self.createItem("18", QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled))
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        '''

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        # create model
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name" , "Points"])
        # create sort proxy
        self.proxy = NumberSortModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        # create view
        self.table = CustomTableView(self)
        self.table.setModel(self.proxy)
        # fill model
        for i in range(10):
            self.model.appendRow([QStandardItem(f'Name{randint(10, 99)}'), 
                                  QStandardItem(str(randint(1, 100)))])
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


        sort_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Sort")
        apply_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Apply")

        horisontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(sort_button)
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(apply_button)
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        grid_layout.addLayout(horisontal_layout, 0, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)

    '''
    def createItem(self, text, flags):
        tableWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text)
        tableWidgetItem.setFlags(flags)
        return tableWidgetItem
    '''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Counter()
    window.setWindowTitle("Counter")
    window.setMinimumSize(480, 380)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]